# Oembed not rendering javascript, only text for Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, oembed

I am using oembed in the Twitter API to embed a tweet widget.  It gets the JSON response just fine, but it shows the tweet in text only, not the embedded widget response.  The javascript that Twitter sends is not firing.

```
  $(document).ready(function() 

  {$.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=133640144317198338&align=center&callback=?", function(data)
    {$('#target').html(data.html);
    });
  });
```

then for the html:

```
<body >
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>
```

=================================================================

Response comes formatted in text only version, instead of the widget.

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck with this as well. If you don't want to deal with jquery you can just use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

and then put into html:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><a href="http://twitter.com/coffee_dad/status/287348974577385474">link</a></blockquote>
```

I'm not sure if this is the proper way, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The dynamically loaded `blockquote` from `oembed` won't get rendered. After digging into `widget.js`, I found that you just need to call `twttr.widgets.load()` after you have added new `blockquote` into your page. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use append. Use $('#target').html(data.html);

Comment: Thanks techfun, I tried it but it still does not render the embedded javascript

Comment: would .html data fix this? I am having the exact same problem as HeatherSpence